# Custom log level disrupts level highlighting

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I'm using log4j 2 with a pattern layout that highlights different log levels. In my code, I specify a custom level. When this level is logged, it's not colored and shows null before the level in the log. Below is my pattern and log snip.

Custom level:

```
final Level STATS = Level.forName("STATS", 510);
```

Pattern:

```
%highlight{%-10.10level}{FATAL=red, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=green, DEBUG=blue, TRACE=blue, STATS=red}
```

Output:

```
Jul 22 15:36:00 INFO          [qtp982337150-23] c.e.class                : Logging an info line
Jul 22 15:36:00 nullSTATS     [qtp982337150-23] c.e.class                : Logging a stats line
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have found a bug. Please raise this on the Log4j2 JIRA issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem with log levels from jul.
I filed an issue in jira for that: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2405

This seems to be the same problem.

**UPDATE 2018-10-24**:

I have prepared a [Pull Request](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/pull/225) that fixes this problem. Hopefully this will be included in Log4j2 soon.